# Неправильное вычисление числа Pi в многопоточности

Tags: c#, многопоточность, математика

Всем привет, скажите пожалуйста почему у меня не правильно вычисляется число pi? То-есть есть примитивная формула [image: Формула нахождения числа pi] и я её короче захотел просчитать, так вот, всё вроде-бы в один дополнительный поток работает хорошо, но я захотел чуть ускорить весь процесс (поэкспериментировать) и решил сделать просчёт суммы `6/n^2` в четырёх разных потоках, но к сожалению у меня вылетает не "3.141.... и т.д.", а какие нибудь совсем левые значения "4.76...", "2.34...", "1.13...". В чём может быть проблема ?

```
decimal sum = 0;
decimal n = 0;

void func()
{
    while (true)
    {
        n++;
        sum = sum + (6 / Convert.ToDecimal(n * n));

        //Console.WriteLine("Поток " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " выводит " + n);            
    }
}

Thread myThread1;
Thread myThread2;
Thread myThread3;
Thread myThread4;

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        myThread1 = new Thread(func); //Создаем новый объект потока (Thread)
        myThread1.Name = "Thread1";
        myThread2 = new Thread(func); //Создаем новый объект потока (Thread)
        myThread2.Name = "Thread2";
        myThread3 = new Thread(func); //Создаем новый объект потока (Thread)
        myThread3.Name = "Thread3";
        myThread4 = new Thread(func); //Создаем новый объект потока (Thread)
        myThread4.Name = "Thread4";
        myThread1.Start(); //запускаем поток
        myThread2.Start(); //запускаем поток
        myThread3.Start(); //запускаем поток
        myThread4.Start(); //запускаем поток
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Content = (Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(sum))).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Проблема в разделяемых данных. Дело с том, что ваши операции неатомарны, а выполнение потоков может пересекаться как угодно.

Представьте себе, что один поток стартовал и увеличил `n`, теперь `n == 1`. В этот момент другой поток стартовал, снова увеличил `n` (теперь `n == 2`), и прибавил к сумме `(6 / Convert.ToDecimal(n * n));`. Теперь первый поток продолжает выполнение, и прибавляет к сумме `(6 / Convert.ToDecimal(n * n));`. Но поскольку `n` уже успело увеличиться, будет прибавлено вовсе не то, что нужно!

Другая проблема, как подсказывает @Igor в комментарии — это то, что в коде `sum = sum + (6 / Convert.ToDecimal(n * n));` значение `sum` может поменяться в другом потоке после вычисления правой части. Смотрите, пусть один поток вычислил значение `sum + (6 / Convert.ToDecimal(n * n))` и хочет записать его в `sum`. В этот самый момент другой поток прибавляет к `sum` очередное слагаемое. Теперь возвращается к выполнению наш поток, и записывает в `sum` новое значение, теряя уже прибавленный другим потоком кусок!

Третья проблема — это неатомарность *присваивания* `decimal`. Дело в том, что `decimal` складывается не за один такт процессора, а значит, на середине сложения может вмешаться снова второй поток и всё испортить. Например, первое присвоение скопировало первое слово результата в переменную, тут прибежал второй поток и переписал новым значением все слова результата. Теперь первый поток продолжает запись, и записывает второе и дальнейшие слова — но первое слово получается вовсе от другого значения! Видите, сколько получается возможных проблем?

---

Есть несколько методов «бороться» с данными проблемами. Один из них — [эксклюзивная блокировка данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) на время работы с ними. Но ваш код состоит лишь из работы с разделяемыми данными, поэтому такая блокировка просто заставит все потоки ждать, пока один из них обрабатывает одну итерацию, тем самым задание будет выполнено *ещё медленее*, чем если бы его делал один поток!

Таким образом, имеет смысл изменить алгоритм, чтобы каждый поток работал лишь с локальными данными. Например, пусть один поток считает лишь каждое четвёртое слагаемое.

Получится примерно такой код:

```
decimal compute(int start, int step, int limit)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    for (long n = start; n < limit; n += step)
        sum += 6 / (decimal)(n * n);
    return sum;
}
```

```
Task<decimal> t0 = Task.Run(() => compute(0, 4, 100000));
Task<decimal> t1 = Task.Run(() => compute(1, 4, 100000));
Task<decimal> t2 = Task.Run(() => compute(2, 4, 100000));
Task<decimal> t3 = Task.Run(() => compute(3, 4, 100000));
decimal result = await t0 + await t1 + await t2 + await t3;
double pi = Math.Sqrt((double)result);
```

---

Для того, чтобы разобраться с тем, как работать с многопоточным кодом, стоит прочитать [online-главу из книги братьев Албахари](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), или её русский перевод: [глава 1](http://www.rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml), [глава 2](http://www.rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading2.xml), [глава 3](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/08/c-3.html), [глава 4](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/08/c-4.html), [глава 5.1](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/09/51.html), [глава 5.2](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/09/52.html).

Comment: и не к тому, к чему нужно :)

Comment: Неслабо текста о многопоточности в шарпе (я о главах книги).

Comment: может, ошибусь, но вроде в примере с кодом должно быть `n += step`

Comment: @etki, точнее `step`

Comment: @etki: Точно! Спасибо.

Comment: @avpда, уже поправил

Comment: @avp: Ага, там описываются все подходы, от простого мьютекса и condition variable до автопараллелизации обхода последовательностей. И это ещё без async/await! Фундаментальный труд.